# telebot, код не работает

Tags: python, telebot

Грубо говоря, сказал я буду на команду /start отвечать приветствие - отвечает, но когда я захотел, чтобы он еще вместе с приветствием спрашивал меня, мол, как дела, то он этого не делает, он все так же приветствует, будто я и не изменял код.

```
import telebot
bot = telebot.TeleBot('АПИ')
@bot.message_handler(commands=['start'])
def start(message):
    mess = f'Привет, {message.from_user.first_name}'
    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, mess)



bot.polling()
```

Comment: Так надо же перезапустить.

Comment: @CrazyElf Так я перезапускаю.
VSC использую. 
ctrl + c, далее повторный запуск, вроде так.)

Comment: Здравствуйте. Сложно ответить на ваш вопрос однозначно. Чтобы избежать путаницы и лишнего флуда, укажите код, в котором, как вы считаете, присутствуют баги или ошибки. Для этого воспользуйтесь соответствующей кнопкой ("Править"). Для оформления кода используйте комбинацию CTRL+K или воспользуйтесь соответствующей кнопок вверху редактора.

Comment: Можете посмотреть, я сделал

Comment: Что значит "не работает"? Он выдаёт ошибку во время сборки, либо во время исполнения? Или же всё запускается без ошибок, но ведёт себя не так как задумывалось? И важное уточнение, у вас отступы в примере так же как в коде расположены? блок кода функции должен иметь отступ.

Comment: Нет, отступы у меня не такие как тут, в коде они как нужно стоят. Проблема в том, что бот работает не так. Пример. Грубо говоря, сказал я буду на команду /start отвечать приветствие - отвечает, но когда я захотел, чтобы он еще вместе с приветствием спрашивал меня, мол, как дела, то он этого не делает, он все так же приветствует, будто я и не изменял код.

Answer (score 0):

У меня ваш код отлично запустился, проверьте ваш API TOKEN в @BotFather.

```
import telebot
bot = telebot.TeleBot('TOKEN')


@bot.message_handler(commands=['start'])
def start(message):
    mess = f'Привет, {message.from_user.first_name}'
    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, mess)


bot.polling()
```

Comment: Что за бред. Грубо говоря, мой код не синхронизируется с ТГ, как бы это странно и глупо не звучало)

Comment: Вам нужно написать @BotFather, создать в нём бота, bot = telebot.TeleBot('АПИ') сюда подставить токен вашего бота и запустить скрипт, после того как вы его запустите, напишите боту /start